# Graph API returns umlaut-letter characters as question marks

Tags: facebook-graph-api, character-encoding

When retrieving data for users with umlaut-letters in their names (ä, ö, etc.), the graph API sometimes returns question marks instead of the letters.

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/1266896428

For a user with name "Anne Jääskeläinen", the graph API returns this:

```
{
   "id": "1266896428",
   "name": "Anne J\u00e4\u00e4skel\u00e4inen",
   "first_name": "Anne",
   "middle_name": "J\u00e4\u00e4skel\u00e4inen",
   "last_name": "j??skel?nen",
   "gender": "female",
   "locale": "fi_FI"
}
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Is this a facebook issue or can I do something about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug in the Facebook Graph API. The bug is now assigned.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/299214506757356?browse=search_4ea6b52d8fda52818597942